# I'm having issue of pushing to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

It's working properly on my local server.

Now, I want to test it before applying onto a live-website.

But, I keep having this error when I try to push to heroku.

Anyone have an idea about this and can help me out?

Thanks.

```
carrey:~/workspace/joy (master) $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 2396, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (743/743), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2396/2396), 13.31 MiB | 1.43 MiB/s, done.
Total 2396 (delta 1520), reused 2396 (delta 1520)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-2.1.5.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-2.1.5.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.1.5
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
remote:  !     
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Debug InformationCommand: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-16/ruby-2.1.5.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to joynus-ian.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/joynus-ian.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/joy-ian.git'
```

Comment: Seems like it might've been an Amazon outage -- it looks to me like Heroku isn't able to connect to the S3 bucket where the Ruby source code was hosted for the buildpack. Have you tried again in the 3 hours since you've asked this question? If so, was it successful then?

Comment: What is the ruby version in your gemfile? It seems that you are using 2.1.5 which is not supported by heroku. try changing the ruby-version

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I figured it out. It was the problem with ruby version.

Answer (score -1):

It is a bit difficult to find reason for the error. Because you did not show the STEPs that you did, to deploy to Heroku. Usually errors are occurred if you miss some required steps. Please, check the following steps and retry again. I hope this will help you to solve your problem. Additionally, I advise you to check the official [Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5) to deploy your app.

=========================

1) check for bundler

```
$ bundle -v
```

=========================

2) if does not exist

```
$ gem install bundler
```

===========================

3) in development group I may use 100s of gems but in production group I will use just a few.
    So, all my configurations must not effected to the production group.

```
$ bundle install —without production
```

=============================

4) install heroku toolbelt (search for google to know more)
    => check for Homebrew installed or not

```
$ brew -v
```

if not installed search on google to install command of Homebrew…
    =>once you are ready, then install heroku toolbelt

```
    $ brew install heroku-toolbelt

    $ heroku update
```

==================================

5) you should sign up to heroku, then

```
$heroku login (*password* for heroku)
```

If you do not have SSH key, yet, it offers you to create new one and say Yes!. If it did not offer any key to applied, you can create manually SSH key.

```
$mkdir ~/.ssh

$ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

===================================

6)  create a heroku to deploy

```
$heroku create
```

===================================

7) before deploy

## commit and push all modified files

8) Add keys:

```
$heroku keys:add
```

===================================

9)

```
$git push heroku master
```

=================================

10) heroku gives a random name to access to project, you can easily change that

```
$heroku rename "new app name"
```

====================================

11) every time you add new models and generate migrations, you have to  deploy migrations also

```
$heroku run rails db:migrate
```

=====================================